Baking the light either takes too long or doesn't work

Why does the baking process take so much time? What I'm sure of is that I won't make a mistake somewhere. Do any of you know my mistake? I'm sure 7 hours is a very long time. At one point, even the sun, which revolved around the terrain like a solar system, was giving the light I wanted. But I don't know where the mistake is in this baking process. If anyone knows and can help I would be very happy.

Try choosing progressive-GPU instead.

I tried, nothing happened.

Do you mean baking failed? Or that it took forever? The GPU solver is usually several orders of magnitude faster than the CPU Solver, assuming you have a supported graphics card. Sounds like there may be an issue with your scene. If you create a new scene with a plane, a cube or some other primitives, do you see the issue?

What version of Unity are you using? What are your computer specs (CPU, GPU, RAM)? How many meshes are in your scene? What's an approximate total polygon count of the scene?

I am using 2020.3.48f1

Cooked the test scene with 5k vertices in 2:32.
